# Neo4j query returning no record

Tags: cypher

Why is the query below not returning any record?

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ATTENDS]->(you1),(a:Person)-[:WORKED_WITH]->(you11), (a:Person)-[:WORKED_WITH]->(you12)
WHERE you1 ="COMP1831"AND you11 = "Python" AND you12 = "Neo4j"
RETURN a,you1,you11,you1
```

I tried to run the query and was expecting it to display
someone that attends COMP1831 and works with both Python and Neo4j

Comment: You cannot compare a node to string. Maybe you meant `you11.name = "Python"`? (Or whatever your properties are, you are not showing them.